# Error while ingesting data into dataverse using Synapse dataflow (Sustainability Manager)

Tags: azure-synapse, common-data-service

I'm trying to load data into dataverse using Azure Synapse pipelines (Dataflows).

Sink: Dataverse table - Mobile combustion (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/common-data-model/schema/core/industrycommon/sustainability/mobilecombustion)

Below are 4 different combinations I tried for Organizational Unit which is a lookup column. I tried attribute name as `msdyn_organizationalunitId` & `msdyn_organizationalunitid` and values as GUID value & name of the organization. None of these combination worked for me.

[image]

Can someone help me with what parameter name and value should I pass for a lookup column while inserting a record in Dataverse entity having lookup property. In this case `Mobile combustion` is the entity name and Organizational unit is the lookup property.

Below is the error message for the last combination:

msdyn_organizationalunitId: 'OrgUnit01'

*Microsoft.OData.ODataException: A 'PrimitiveValue' node with non-null value was found when trying to read the value of the property 'msdyn_organizationalunitId'; however, a 'StartArray' node, a 'StartObject' node, or a 'PrimitiveValue' node with null value was expected.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending a couple of months this is what worked for me.

```
Column name: 'msdyn_organizationalunitId@odata.bind'
Column Value: '/msdyn_sustainabilityorganizationalunits(<OrgUnitGUIDValue>)'
```

For any dynamics entity, while writing data to an entity with reference columns, your data set must have reference column names ended with '@odata.bind' and column value must be in '/ReferenceEntity(GUIDValue)' format.